# how to list all available user defined macros in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Say in my main code I have this code block:

```
%macros hi5;
 %put hi five;
%mend;

%macros helloworld;
  %put hello world;
%mend;
```

How do I, in SAS Enterprise Guide, display something like this? (via log or via a SAS table)

```
These are the user defined user macros:

hi5
hello world
```

(the aim is so that user is able to know what macros are already available to them).

Note: the `%put _ALL_` only list all macros variables, not macros (e.g. built with `%macros and %mend`.)

Comment: All _compiled_ SAS Macros are stored in a catalog names **SASMACR** which is saved in **WORK** with _entry type_ **MACRO**. I would try **PROC CATALOG** , have never tried using this. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Gaurav (thanks for suggesting!), I've actually tried `proc catalog cat=work.sasmacr; contents out=_temp; quit;` - on SAS EG it says work.sasmacr doesn't exist. (In my old work place this used to work on base SAS. In new work place I am on Enterprise guide no base SAS).

Comment: Instead of `work.sasmacr` try `SASHELP.VCATALG` ( blatantly copied from https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Session-compiled-macro-catalog/td-p/77942 )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get there via `PROC CATALOG`, or via `dictionary.catalogs`.  The latter will work even if you don't know where they're stored.

```
proc sql;
  select * 
    from dictionary.catalogs
    where objtype='MACRO';
quit;
```

That will include the predefined macros in `SASHELP`, which you can exclude using `where libname ne 'SASHELP'`.

Comment: Awesome!!! I run the SQL Query with the added `where ... AND libname ne "SASHELP"` - it now shows me the user defined macro. (I didn't know about this `dictionary table` thing before! Learnt something new today thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

When you are running SAS using Enterprise Guide, SAS/Studio or other new fangled access methods the compiled macros that would previously appear in `WORK.SASMACR` catalog now end up in `WORK.SASMAC1`. At least in the environments I have explored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using proc catalogs

```
proc catalog cat=xxxxx.sasmacr;contents;run;
```