# Get case sensitive list of macros in program

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143108/how-to-list-all-available-user-defined-macros-in-sas-enterprise-guide), I can get a list of compiled macros in a program, ordered by their first appearance, using the following code:

```
%macro FirstMacro();
  %put Hello, World!;
%mend;

%macro SecondMacro();
  %put Goodbye, cruel world!;
%mend;

proc sql;
  select objname, created
  from dictionary.catalogs
  where objtype='MACRO' and libname ^= 'SASHELP'
  order by created
  ;
quit;
```

This, however, gives all the macros in uppercase.

```
               Object Name                           Date Created
               --------------------------------------------------
               FIRSTMACRO                        09FEB17:16:12:31
               SECONDMACRO                       09FEB17:16:12:31
```

I use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for my macro names (as illustrated above).  Is there a way to get a similar list, but with case sensitivity preserved?

It seems like [PROC SCAPROC](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/69850/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0sf63lx4fs2m5n14qv1bn8p863v.htm) might provide such a list, but it's unclear to me. There is a [note](http://support.sas.com/kb/48/812.html) from when PROC SCAPROC was first released (in 9.2) that indicates that PROC SCAPROC doesn't provide support for when a %MACRO is used.  However, the note says this will be a feature in future versions of SAS.  With SAS 9.4 it's unclear whether the feature has been added yet.

The only other alternative I can think of is to write a script in some other language which analyzes the text above for the macro names.

Comment: What is the purpose for this particular exercise?  IE, once you have this list, what's it going to be used for?

Comment: Macro names are not case sensitive so why would SAS store them in mixed case?

Comment: @Tom I'm going to guess (and I asked for this reason) that OP is using this to generate code and/or for an EG add-in to improve the rather limited macro autocomplete functionality, and wants the PascalCase text as an output.  (If OP is indeed writing an add-in for this, I would love to have it, and/or help write it - this would be a super useful tool!)

Comment: In my particular case, I need the list for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's feasible this may give you what you want, at least with the above example.

It does not expand the macro when it's run - meaning, you don't get to see what happens *inside* the macro, *as it runs*.  This may be a problem if you are generating macros at runtime, i.e. using your data to create macros - like

```
data _null_;
  set something;
  call execute ('%macro ',name_var,'; ... ; %mend;');
run;
```

That may not show up properly.  But if you're just writing macros in code and compiling them, then yes, you might be able to use this - though you have to run the compilation step at least as part of this (this doesn't analyse plaintext, it analyzes a job while it runs).

So if I do something like this:

```
proc scaproc;
  record 'c:\temp\recording.txt' expandmacros;
run;

%macro PascalCaseMacro();
  %put PascalCaseMacro;
%mend;

%PascalCaseMacro;

proc scaproc; 
   write; 
run;
```

I get output like this:

```
/* JOBSPLIT: PROCNAME DATASTEP */
/* A bunch of lines like that with JOBSPLIT at the start */


%macro PascalCaseMacro();
  %put PascalCaseMacro;
%mend;

%PascalCaseMacro;

/* Some more JOBSPLIT lines */
```

You could then parse that text file for lines that started with `%macro`.

I do think the technical answer to your question is "no", they have not implemented this: while it does update the technical information with some accesses of the macro catalog, it doesn't ever include in the detail of what macro was run (in the /* JOBSPLIT */ lines).  That's really what that technical note is talking about, I think; i.e., this is not perfectly useful for optimizing macro code. The actual code that generates the macro (which I think is all *you* need) is there.  (However, if you have a stored-compiled-macro, that would *not* be available.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt the Windows Batch Script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042909/extract-part-of-a-text-file-using-batch-dos/19457160) post to get a list of case sensitive macros defined in a given program.

```
REM GetListOfDefinedMacros.bat

@ECHO OFF

SET /P SASFILE= Enter SAS filepath: 
SET SASFILE=%SASFILE:"=%

ECHO.
ECHO The defined macros are:
ECHO.

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR "macro" "%SASFILE%" ^| FINDSTR "("') DO CALL :FindString "%%A"
ECHO. 
pause
GOTO :eof

:FindString
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:*macro =%
SET String=%String:)=X%
SET String=%String:(=`%
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%A IN ('ECHO.%String%') DO ECHO.%%A
GOTO :eof
```

The program prompts the user for the SAS program's full file path.  It then parses the code, looking for lines which contain both "`macro`" and "`(`", returning the any characters that lie between them.

The following assumptions must hold:

- each line contains a single programming statement; "`macro`" and "`(`" must be on the same line,
- a macro is defined using parentheses; it will not work for `%macro MacroName;` style definitions.

Note that the script doesn't list compiled macros.  It can only detect macros which have definitions within the given program.  Macros compiled through `%include` or AUTOCALL will not show up.

For example,

```
/*C:\temp\sample sas program.sas*/

%macro FirstMacro();
  %put NOTE: Hello, world!;
%mend;

%macro SecondMacro();
  %put ERROR: Goodbye, cruel world!;
%mend;

%macro ThirdMacro(input);
  %if &input. = hi %then %FirstMacro();
  %else %SecondMacro();
%mend;

%ThirdMacro(hi);
%ThirdMacro(bye);
```

This gives the following output to the command prompt:

```
Enter SAS filepath: "C:\temp\sample sas program.sas"

The defined macros are:

FirstMacro
SecondMacro
ThirdMacro

Press any key to continue . . .
```

From there, you can copy and paste the list.  Or, the code could be modified to redirect the list to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a native SAS solution which should rely only on BASE capabilities.  It is intended for use in the Enhanced Editor on Windows.

````
%macro ListMacroDefinitions();
  /*Get file-path of current program's source code.*/
  proc sql noprint;
    select distinct xpath
    into : _SASProgramPath trimmed
    from dictionary.extfiles
    where xpath contains "%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME)"
    ;
  quit;

  /*Read in source code, parse for macro names, and
    output to log.*/
  options nonotes;
  data _null_;
    infile "&_SASProgramPath." dlm = '```';
    length 
      line        $ 256
      macro_name  $ 32
    ;
    input line;

    if line =: '%macro' then do;
      indexLeftParenthesis  = index(line, '(');
      macroNameLength       = indexLeftParenthesis - 8;
      macro_name            = substr(line, 8, macroNameLength); 
      put macro_name;
    end;
  run;
  options notes;
  dm 'wpgm';
%mend;
````

It works by first determining what the current program's name is using `%sysget(SAS_EXECFILENAME)`.  The [%SYSGET](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/69726/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19zyt041jjgs7n16ps5awotxnik.htm) function returns the value of the [environment variable](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/090-2010.pdf) SAS_EXECFILENAME which

> specifies the filename of the current SAS source file, if it is
>   submitted from the enhanced editor.

It then looks in the `DICTIONARY.EXTFILES` [table](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/259-31.pdf) and extracts a file path associated with name of the current source file (i.e. the program currently being edited).  This file path is assigned to a macro variable.

Next, a data step reads in the source file of the current program. It reads the file line by line setting a non-existent delimiter (three back ticks) in the [INFILE](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/69738/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm#p1fdvsp2n4yna3n1ht0222w1okyl) statement.

> By default, if the INPUT statement tries to read past the end of the
>   current input data record, then it moves the input pointer to column 1
>   of the next record to read the remaining values.

Defining the delimiter to a string which never appears in the source code causes the line read in to never be parsed and thus be read in whole.  Each line is checked for whether it [contains](http://support.sas.com/kb/43/303.html) a macro definition (via the `=:` operator).  Specifically, it looks for the string '%macro'.  We then manually parse each definition line for the characters between the '%macro ' statement and the first parenthesis.  The result is output to the log.  During this process, notes are disabled.  Finally, the windowing command `wpgm` is issued.  When the macro names are written to the log, the log window is selected.  The `wpgm` command returns focus to the last program window, which should be the program currently being edited.

The whole process is put inside a macro.  If you place the macro in an [AUTOCALL](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p017-27.pdf) library (found by issuing `%put %sysfunc(pathname(sasautos));`), you can get a list of all the macros defined within your current program.  Note that for this list to be complete, you must save your current program before running the macro.